# Need help with bzr

Tags: bazaar

I'm trying to install dodge-maximize, when i write "bzr push lp:~kbailey4444/wingpanel/dodge-maximize" i get an error saying "bzr: ERROR: Not a branch: "/home/lukaruso/"." can you help me trying to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

To download `dodge-maximize`, please do

```
$ bzr branch lp:~kbailey4444/wingpanel/dodge-maximize
```

... and the folder `dodge-maximize/` will appear. ( Size = 1.1MB ) https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/en/Bazaar#Repositories → To check out a copy

---

In dodge-maximize/, please read the file INSTALL.

Install the build prerequisites for dodge-maximize →

```
sudo apt install g++ cmake libgranite-dev libindicator3-dev libido3-0.1-dev libwnck-3-dev
```

If you never have built/compiled any applications, there may be some more (lib)name-**dev** to install.

Build dodge-maximize

```
cd dodge-maximize/
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ../
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Already did that, i can't seem to understand what to do after that.

Comment: So far I don't know what the application is supposed to do. Please edit your original question to show a description. Build dodge-maximize: See my edited answer.